# Facebook Android SDK issue with targeting api level 33

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm currently getting the error from Facebook SDK when attempting to sign in with Facebook on Android, with a device running Android 13.

The error shows:

```
Login Error: There is an error in logging you into this application. Please try again later.
```

I've looked into quite a few solutions talking about the key hash for meta is not valid or empty.

I have checked that the key hash is not empty, I also doubt the hash is invalid as when I'm using an android 11 device I do not get the error I only started encountering the error because I had to update an app to target api level 33 which is android 13.

When I look at the android facebook sdk versions at:

```
https://play.google.com/sdks/details/com-facebook-android-facebook-android-sdk
```

I notice the latest version is `16.2.0`, which is the one I'm currently using but it only targets api level 31. This makes me think if the facebook android sdk has not been updated to accommodate the google play requirements:

```
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/11926878?hl=en#:~:text=When%20you%20update%20your%20app,target%20API%2033%20or%20above.&text=Existing%20apps-,When%20you%20publish%20a%20new%20app%2C%20you%20must%20target%20API,is%20compliant%20with%20this%20policy.
```

Is anyone else experiencing the same issue? Am I missing something? I should mention I have followed:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android
```

and I've set `implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.0-alpha05'` in `build.gradle`.